# Will Apple charge for a doctor/patient video calling app if the call is being charged by the doctor?

Tags: ios, video, call

I want to make an app through which patients can consult doctors through video calling and would be charged by the doctor based on the duration of the call. 
Will apple take a share from each transaction?

Comment: Apple take 30% of revenue through the App Store and in-app purchases, but it's possible to charge users elsewhere for content they access through the app (see Comixology/Amazon), so the answer is: it depends on how you charge the user.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about apple app charge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple only takes its cut from the purchase of **paid apps** and the purchase of **in-app purchases**. They charge `30%` of what each user pays to them.

You can integrate your own payment methods for calls etc if you want to charge user for each call. So, there would be no involvement of Apple in this transaction.

Comment: My app got approved. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi @hamza,  What did you implement - In App Purchase or any other payment gateway??